# Regular expression (extract key/value pairs)

Tags: regex, qt, key-value, text-extraction

I'm trying to extract a list (match) of key/value pairs from a string. Ex :

```
PATH_1:"/", PATH_2:"/OtherPath", TODAY:"2016-06-27",XYZ :"1234"
```

This should give :

```
      Key            Value
      PATH_1         /
      PATH_2         /OtherPath
      TODAY          2016-06-27
      XYZ            1234
```

Here is what I have so far as regex :

```
((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*):((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*)
```

This is well working except that when I'm adding a path having a '\'. Ex :

```
PATH_1:"c:\", PATH_2:"c:\OtherPath", TODAY:"2016-06-27"
```

I don't know how to instruct to regex expression to jump over semi-colon when found inside double quote sequence. Hope someone can help me.

PS : I'm using QT.

Best regards,

Comment: It looks to be [working](https://regex101.com/r/vB1rS1/1).

Comment: Yes, that Is what I noticed too :(
The string is read from a QSettings (ini) and it seems that double quote are remove when getting the key's value. Thus the regular expression is no longer working :( What a mess...   By the way, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: "jump over semi-colon"? There are no semicolons anywhere in your input. This is semi-colon: `;` this is colon: `:`.

Comment: Barmar: sorry typing error. This is a COLON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/vB1rS1/2

It seems that just removing the `:` from the last `[]` may do it if the quotes are being removed.

```
((?:"[^"]*"|[^:,])*):((?:"[^"]*"|[^,])*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Will :) Really great explanation. By the way, is there a way to NOT INCLUDE the double quote from the capturing group ? But keep it if they are escaped using \" ? Best regards,

Comment: over a year later: yes, I'm not 100% on exactly what you desire so I'm not going to give a regex, but it sounds like something you could definitely do