# how to convert the string into name value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the string into key value pair. I had tried with this code, but I not able to get the expected output,

```js
const result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData firstName="John" lastname="joe" gender="M" empNo="32323" city="xxxx" address="xxxxx line22 tn" />';
const r1 = result.replace(/\s/g, ',');

console.log(r1.split(','));
```

the above is a sample string, the value will be change.
my expected output should be

```
[{firstName:"John", lastname:"joe", gender:"M", empNo:"32323", city:"xxx", address:"xxxx line22 tn"}]
```

Comment: why you think a result.replace(/\s/g,',') will provide the output you expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057771/regular-expression-extract-key-value-pairs

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I have no idea what to do next

Comment: You need to parse the XML, see here for how to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML. From there you can work on getting the desired output. Better stop trying to use a Regex, it is totally unsuitable for parsing XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the string is representing an XML, you should use it as such.
So, use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse it:

```js
const result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData firstName="John" lastname="joe" gender="M" empNo="32323" city="xxxx" address="xxxxx line22 tn" />';

const parser = new DOMParser()
const doc = parser.parseFromString(result, "application/xml")

console.log(doc.documentElement.getAttribute("firstName")) // "John"
```

And if you still need the plain object, you can easily create from it:

```js
const obj = [...doc.documentElement.attributes].reduce((acc, attr) => (
  acc[attr.name] = attr.value, acc
), {});

console.log(obj); // Object { firstName: "John", lastname: "joe", gender: "M", empNo: "32323", city: "xxxx", address: "xxxxx line22 tn" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData firstName="John" lastname="joe" gender="M" empNo="32323" city="xxxx" address="xxxxx line22 tn" />';
const r1 = result.split(' ');


let final = {};

for(let i=0; i<r1.length; i++ ){
   if(i>3 && i<10 ){
   
   let temp = r1[i].split("=")
       final[temp[0]] = temp[1].replace(`"`, "").replace(`"`, "");
   }
}

console.log(final);
```

Answer would be,

```
{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastname: 'joe',
  gender: 'M',
  empNo: '32323',
  city: 'xxxx',
  address: 'xxxxx'
}
```

You can put this to an empty array.